# LINQ select statement with many to many

Tags: c#, linq

I have a relationship, project categories. This relation is many to many so i have three tables: Project / project_has_category / categories.

I need to select all projects that has a relation with a certain category (by its id)

### Project class

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

### Category class

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Projects(string catID, string strSearch)
{
    var cats = Adapter.CategoryRepository.Get();
    var projects = Adapter.ProjectRepository.Get().Where(x => x.Categories.Contains(catID));
    /*also*/
    var projects = Adapter.ProjectRepository.Get().Where(x => cats.Contains(catID));
    return View(projects);
}
```

But this gives the error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.Contains(LibModels.Category)'
>   has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\Freelauncher1005\Freelauncher\Controllers\ProjectController.cs

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Categories is a list of `Category` objects, you can't search for integer id with `Contains` method (check signature of this method - it requires `Category` object to search for):

```
  var projects = Adapter.ProjectRepository.Get()
                        .Where(x => x.Categories.Contains(catID)) // error
```

Use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338.aspx) to check if there is `Category` object with id equal to your value:

```
  var projects = Adapter.ProjectRepository.Get()
                        .Where(x => x.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryID == catID))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the ID to int first and use Any then

```
var id = int.Parse(catID);
Adapter.ProjectRepository.Get().Where(x => x.Categories.Any(y => y.CategoryID == id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var projects = Adapter.ProjectRepository
                      .Get()
                      .Where(p => p.Categories
                                   .Any(c => c.CategoryID == catID));
```

or possibly

```
var projects = Adapter.CategoryRepository
                      .Get()
                      .Where(c => c.CategoryID == catID)
                      .Select(c => c.Projects)
                      .Distinct();
```

to query it from the other direction